# How to validate user or authenticate programmatically in ASP.NET MVC 5.1.2 OWIN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

How to validate user in ASP.NET MVC 5.1.2 ?

In older versions of MVC 3,4 we had simple membership. So we do use membership.validate(user.name,password). But things have changed completly in asp.net mvc 5.

After programmatic login like

```
   await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe); // after login HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false . Odd.
   private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent) {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(Manager));
    }
```

There is no previous authentication system. To validate a user we can do this :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        public static ApplicationUserManager Manager {
        get {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserAsync(string userName, string password) {
        return await Manager.FindAsync(userName: userName, password: password);
    }
    public static ApplicationUser GetUserByEmail(string email, string password) {
        var user = Manager.FindByEmail(email);
        return Manager.Find(user.UserName, password);
    }
```

if those does return any user then we have to assume that user is valid or else not.